# Getting the corresponding record of a Cursor/Select when in a Cursor LOOP statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-cursor

The question seems easy. I have built a package, where there is a quite massive cursor, let's say on all invoices of my company for the whole year.

```
    CURSOR c_invoices(p_year IN INTEGER) IS
    SELECT     all_invoices.invoicenumber,   
               all_invoices.invoicedate,
               all_invoices.customernumber
    FROM       all_invoices
    WHERE      all_invoices.year = p_year 
    ;
```

After opening it and using a LOOP statement, I want to get some data from another table (forbidden_customers), but only if the customer is in this very last table.

What I'd like to do, is to open another cursor (or a SELECT ?) at the very beginning of my package, browsing the whole table(forbidden_customers), and then getting to the corresponding record when in my invoices LOOP.

So, something like :

```
        CURSOR     c_forbidden_customers IS
        SELECT     forbidden_customers.customernumber,   
                   forbidden_customers.customeradress
        FROM       forbidden_customers
        ;
```

And then :

```
OPEN    c_invoices(v_year);
        LOOP FETCH c_invoices INTO invoices_cursor;
        BEGIN
        EXIT WHEN c_invoices%NOTFOUND; 
             *IF invoices_cursor.customernumber IS FOUND IN c_forbidden_customers ...
                 THEN ...*
```

This is what I do meanwhile (I know it is bad):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO v_exist /*INTEGER*/
FROM forbidden_customers
WHERE forbidden_customers.customernumber= p_customernumber

IF v_exist <> 0 
    THEN...
```

I tried to make it as clear as possible. Thank you for your time

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; a **MINIMAL** example of your code (or a similar problem to your code); the issues/errors with your code; and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it twice; join both tables in the same cursor and use it. Also, if you switch to a cursor FOR loop, you'll save yourself from some typing as Oracle will do most of *boring* stuff for you (declaring cursor variable, opening the cursor, closing it, exiting the loop ...):

```
create or replace procedure p_test (p_year in integer) is
begin
  for c_invoices in 
    (select a.invoicenumber,
            a.invoicedate,
            a.customernumber,
            c.customeraddress
     from all_invoices a join forbidden_customers c on c.customernumber = a.customernumber
     where a.year = p_year)
  loop
    -- do something
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Better to use outer join, since not all customers are in forbidden_customers table.

Comment: Maybe, @Michael. The way I understood it, the OP wants to "do something" only for matching rows. If not, then yes - outer join would be better.

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot for this. Unfortunately, I cannot do this as 1. I have to do it on multiple tables, and the query would be enormous, and 2. I've tried it before but it would make the query much, much slower.

Comment: Fetching FORBIDEEN_CUSTOMERS data separately won't speed it up. Did you properly index all columns involved in joins? Do you regularly gather schema statistics (so that Oracle would be able to use optimal execution plan)?

Comment: Yes, everything revolving around the database itself is properly done. Statistics are gathered at least once a day. Problem is, if I do this, my program will look like an enormous query, which is not really what I'm looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

If the table forbidden_customers is not large and it will fit oracle's session memory, you can use a pl/sql table to store all id's from forbidden_customers and check it later. The check is done in memory only, so it is much faster than any regular select.

```
create table all_invoices
(id number,
year number,
customer_number number);

create table forbidden_customers
(customer_number number);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_number_table IS TABLE OF number
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test23
IS
    forbidden_customers_list   t_number_table;

    CURSOR c_invoices (p_year IN INTEGER)
    IS
        SELECT all_invoices.customer_number
          FROM all_invoices
         WHERE all_invoices.year = p_year;
BEGIN
   SELECT customer_number
   BULK   COLLECT INTO forbidden_customers_list
   FROM   forbidden_customers;
   
    FOR rec_invoices  in c_invoices(2022) loop
        if forbidden_customers_list.exists(rec_invoices.customer_number) then
    null;
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
/
```